# The calls of my own domain repository that extend FE user of TYPO3 7.6 don't work

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have in the model of my own extension a class that extends of FE user of TYPO3 7.6 call CommunityManager, I want to use the calls common to the repository like `findByUid()` or `findAll()` but they do not work, the value of return is `Null`.

I've been researching about it, even in several here questions but it still does not work. I currently have the following settings

In my CommunityManagerController

```
/**
 * communityManagerRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
 protected $communityManagerRepository = null;

/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function listAction()
  {
    $this->communityManagerRepository = $this->objectManager->get('VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CommunityManagerRepository');
    $communityManagers = $this->communityManagerRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('communityManagers', $communityManagers);
  }
```

The CommunityManagerRepository

```
class CommunityManagerRepository extends TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
{
  public function initializeObject()
  {
    $defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings::class);
    $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
  }
 }
```

And the Typoscript code

In constants

```
plugin.tx_myext_nameofmyplugin {
  persistence {
    storagePid = 5
  }
}
```

In setup

```
 config.tx_extbase {
  persistence {
    classes {

      TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
        subclasses {
          Tx_MyExt_CommunityManager = VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager

        }
      }
      VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager {
        mapping {
          tableName = fe_users
          recordType = Tx_MyExt_CommunityManager
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate you guiding me to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the VENDOR and MyExt are correct in your setup and that the model CommunityManager exists.

```
class CommunityManager extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
}

class CommunityManagerRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {
}
```

In a similar situation I had to extend the setup a bit with subclasses and recordType:

```
config.tx_extbase { 
        persistence {
                classes {
                        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                                subclasses {
                                        Tx_MyExt_CommunityManager = VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager

                                }
                        }
                        VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager {
                                mapping {
                                        tableName = fe_users
                                        recordType = Tx_MyExt_CommunityManager
                                }
                        }

                }
        }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374970/7896428

Comment: Yes, the model `CommunityManager` extends directly of `FrontendUser`. I set the typoscript and change the extend or `CommunityManagerRepository` for extbase `Repository` but it doesn't work yet

Comment: I found this Typoscript in the file ext_typoscript_setup.txt , generates by Extension Builder

Comment: Just needed to modify the type field in the fe_users table and associate it with our own extension

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you are using the inject-annotation to load a repository of type `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository`, but you overriding it in your action with your `VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CommunityManagerRepository`. You can simply add your own repository classname in the type-annotation of your communityManagerRepository-property.
Second: Don't use the inject-annotation. Do your injections with an inject method like so:

```
class CommunityManagerController extends TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController{
        /**
     * The communityManagerRepository
     *
     * @var \VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManagerRepository
     */
    protected $communityManagerRepository;

    /**
     * Inject the communityManagerRepository
     *
     * @param \VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManagerRepository $communityManagerRepository
     */
    public function injectCommunityManagerRepository(\VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManagerRepository $communityManagerRepository){
        $this->communityManagerRepository = $communityManagerRepository;
    }
}
```

The inject-annotation is bad to use. You can read here, why it is: https://gist.github.com/NamelessCoder/3b2e5931a6c1af19f9c3f8b46e74f837

Now you don't need the line with the objectManager, because the inject-method does this for you.

Finally, according to your configuration, the communityManagerRepository will return objects of type `\VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager`, but your storagePid setting will be ignored because of the `$defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);`.
Anyway, you should be getting all the fe_users records present in the system now, unless you added a new recordType for the fe_users in the persistence settings of your model (which you don't according to your example). Then extbase will only return fe_users records of the right recordType to you.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. What is the correct way for call `$this->injectCommunityManagerRepository($communityManagerRepository)`, what object should send it, because the only object, that I see, it will be the property `$communityManagerRepository`?

Comment: The inject-method doesn't have to be called by you. The object manager that instantiates your controller will do so on its own.

Answer (score 2):

My answer might be too late for this post. But I came across same issue and after debugging extbase classes I found solution.

Your setup is fine; except 1 missing variable **recordTypeColumnName** (This should be field in record of fe_users table that contains value "Tx_MyExt_CommunityManager").

In my own solution I took advantage of **pid** column in table row. As I know id of my storage folder, which will remain constant for all my records in extension.

There is 2 ways to set value of **recordTypeColumnName**:

**Method 1:**

In TCA set type in ctrl array.

```
  $GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['type'] = 'pid';
```

**Method 2:**

In TypoScript constants.txt

```
  PID.myStorage = 5
```

In TypoScript setup.txt

```
  plugin.tx_MyExt.persistence.storagePid = {$PID.myStorage}

  config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
      classes {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
          subclasses {
            {$PID.myStorage} = VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager
          }
          recordTypeColumnName = pid
        }

        VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\CommunityManager {
          mapping {
            tableName = fe_users
            recordType = {$PID.myStorage}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are few points to check here:**

**1.**
Check if in fe_users with `pid` 5 you have users stored.

**2.** Check if the extension `typoscript` is added to `template`.

**3.** Go in install tool and press `clear cache button`

**4.** There, in Controller, you don't use the `CommunityManagerRepository` but `FrontendUserRepository` from `extbase` you can pass first and second step if you use the `CommunityManagerRepository` because there you set the `respectStorage` to `false`.

Comment: But your repository is loaded, only the data is not returned, yes ?

Comment: Excuse me, how could check it? the repository loaded

Comment: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->communityManagerRepository) this in Controller

Comment: Thank you. My repository is not loaded, when I call the function that you sent me the answer is `Extbase Variable Dump: NULL`

Comment: Clear cache from install tool and remove folder typo3temp/autoload. Then reload the page, after the page is loaded go in typo3temp/autoload/autoload_classmap.php and search by CommunityManagerRepository. If you can't find the class maybe the namesapce it's the problem.

Comment: Thank you, now the repository is loaded. But the data is not return.

Comment: Cool. Did you try `$this->communityManagerRepository->findAll();` and set `storagePid` with your users `sys_folder`. Normally should work if already data exists and if you have set correctly the `storagePid` or set respectStorage to false. Also you can create a empty user `entity` and `add` it with `communityManagerRepository`. If your data is not added in fe_users table there is a problem, the mapping isn't correct so you have to check `extbase` config.