# TYPO3 Extension Builder Integrate of existing table

Tags: typo3, extension-builder3

I tried to integrate an existing table to my extension. The problem is that the content of the table isn't taken over.
I created a new model with the name of the existing table and named the properties according to the existing column names. I also implemented the corresponding getters and setters of the properties.

[Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQVlD.png)

The name of the existing table is `tx_institutsseminarverwaltung_domain_model_event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issues is:

First get the Typo3 query settings

```
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
```

Set RespectStoragePage to false

```
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
```

Fetch your repository

```
    $theRepository = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\institutsseminarverwaltung\\Domain\\Repository\\EventRepository');
```

And set the query settings to your repository.

```
    $theRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to "consume" or access the data from the other table in your extension?

Do you have a repository for the existing table (maybe there is already an existing repository, that you can reuse)?

See [german typo3 board mapping existing tables](https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/118413/seite/2/) and [SO thread TYPO3 / How to make repository from existing table fe_users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254124/typo3-how-to-make-repository-from-existing-table-fe-users)

This question is most likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380221/typo3-accessing-an-existing-table-to-consume-data-of-it)