# Typo3 accessing an existing table to consume data of it

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I tried to integrate an existing table to my extension. The problem is that the content of the table isn't taken over. I created a new model with the name of the existing table and named the properties according to the existing column names. I also implemented the corresponding getters and setters of the properties.

[image]

The name of the existing table is `tx_institutsseminarverwaltung_domain_model_event.`

What is my failure in this case? Just want to access the data of an existing table from another extension.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this:

```
/**
 * Protected Variable objectManager wird mit NULL initialisiert.
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
 * @inject
 */
protected $objectManager = NULL;
```

and listAction():

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {
    echo "test";
    $theRepository = $this->objectManager->get('\TYPO3\institutsseminarverwaltung\Domain\Repository\EventRepository');
    $yourRecords = $theRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('events', $yourRecords);
}
```

But no results returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is:

```
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

    $theRepository = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\institutsseminarverwaltung\\Domain\\Repository\\EventRepository');
    $theRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);

    $yourRecords = $theRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('events', $yourRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the repository linked to this table. Something like this :

```
$theRepository = $this->objectManager->get(\Your\VendorName\Domain\Repository\TheRepository::class);
$yourRecords = $theRepository->findAll();
```

Comment: I added some info in question above. No errors, but no data is fetched ... what could be a problem?

Comment: do I have to set the storage pid?

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to "consume" or access the data from the other table in your extension?

Do you have a repository for the existing table (maybe there is already an existing repository, that you can reuse)?

See [german typo3 board mapping existing tables](https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/118413/seite/2/) and [SO thread TYPO3 / How to make repository from existing table fe_users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254124/typo3-how-to-make-repository-from-existing-table-fe-users)